# Flat file population of

Tags: excel, vba

I import a massive amount of data from SharePoint as a new worksheet (“The Pull”) on an existing book that has four other sections.  I am trying to develop a macro that will, when run, a.) automatically filter the data by a field in the Pull; b.) copy/”paste values” of that filtered data into an existing sheet starting at cell A5; c.) reset the filter on the Pull for the next sheet.

So for example, in the Pull (default worksheet name “owssvr”), each row has a date in Column AR showing when the item in that row was created.  How do I automatically filter for all items from the previous month in the pull (or alternatively, give the user the option to choose the month), and copy/paste values of the filtered result into a worksheet called “Monthly Report” starting at cell A5 (allowing for the header to not change)?  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would write that:

```
Option Explicit

Sub MonthFilter()
Dim LR As Long, MyDate As Date, d1 As Date, d2 As Date

MyDate = Application.InputBox("Enter any date in the month you wish to pull", "Enter Date", Date - 30, Type:=2)
If MyDate = 0 Then
    Exit Sub
Else
    d1 = DateSerial(Year(MyDate), Month(MyDate), 1)
    d2 = DateSerial(Year(MyDate), Month(MyDate) + 1, 1) - 1
End If

With Sheets("The Pull")
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    .Rows(1).AutoFilter
    .Rows(1).AutoFilter 44, Criteria1:=">=" & d1, _
           Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & d2
    LR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 44).End(xlUp).Row
    If LR > 1 Then .Range("A2:A" & LR).EntireRow.Copy Sheets("Monthly Report").Range("A5")
    .AutoFilterMode = False
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AutoFilter` and `ShowAllData` to filter and unfilter. Here is an example.

```
Sub CopyLastMonthFromThePull(shtCopyTo As Worksheet)
   Dim rngPullTable As Range, iColumnToFilter As Integer, strMonth As String

   ' this assumes that the pull data is the first Excel Table on ThePull worksheet named owssvr
   Set rngPullTable = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("owssvr").ListObjects(1).Range
   rngPullTable.Parent.Activate

   ' determine the filter details
   strMonth = CStr(DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) - 1, Day(Date))) ' one month prior to today
   iColumnToFilter = 44    ' Column AR is the 44th column

   ' filter the table
   rngPullTable.AutoFilter Field:=iColumnToFilter, Operator:=xlFilterValues _
                     , Criteria2:=Array(1, strMonth)
   DoEvents

   ' copy the filtered results. (This also copies the header row.)
   rngPullTable.Copy
   With shtCopyTo
      .Activate
      .Range("A5").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
      .Columns.AutoFit
      .Range("A1").Select
   End With
   Application.CutCopyMode = False

   ' remove filter
   With rngPullTable.Parent
      .Activate
      .ShowAllData
   End With
   rngPullTable.Range("A1").Select

   ' End with the sheet being copied to active
   shtCopyTo.Activate

End Sub
```